# Why don't delays work when I'm attempting to flash an error message?

Tags: c#, delay, display, blocking

**Problem:** I'm working on a calculator as my first MVVM application and have come across an interesting problem that I would like to understand better. My noob problem is that I'm trying to flash an error message for an invalid input--in this case I don't want the user to use the negate operator in an invalid location. In order to flash the message across the screen, I'm saving the display in another variable, setting the display to say "Invalid Operation", then I'd like to delay for half a second and reset the display to what it was before (from the temp variable). My problem is that the display variable gets set but the actual display doesn't update to show the error message, no matter how long the delay is.

**I've tried** both blocking (Thread.Sleep) and non-blocking delays (Task.Delay) within the function, writing separate functions to set and reset the display, and delaying within the Negate function instead, but none of these attempts allow the display to update. The display works as expected when adding and deleting characters in other parts of the code, so I don't think there's an issue with that.

Is this some sort of piping issue (the delay function actually starts before it can call the Display property) or something else entirely? I've checked other posts on here and those solutions don't seem to solve my issue. I'd love feedback on why this doesn't work as I'd expect it to as well as more efficient/effective ways to code this. Here are the relevant code blocks:

```
        public void Negate()
        {
            if (Display.Length > 0)
            {
                if (Display[Display.Length - 1].Equals('-'))
                {
                    Display = Display.Substring(0, Display.Length - 1);
                }
                else if (Display[Display.Length - 1].Equals(' ') || Display[Display.Length - 1].Equals('(') ||
                    Display[Display.Length - 1].Equals('E') || Display[Display.Length - 1].Equals('^'))
                {
                    Display += '-';
                }
                else
                {
                    InvalidOperation();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Display = "-";
            }
        }
```

```
        public void InvalidOperation()
        {
            tempDisplay = Display;
            Display = "Invalid Operation";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Display = tempDisplay;
        }
```

```
        public string Display
        {
            get
            {
                return _display;
            }
            set
            {
                _display = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using Sleep on the UI thread is a bad idea - your app becomes unresponsive e.g. the window can't be moved while in the sleep call. Instead use a timer to reset the status display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI will be updated only after method `InvalidOperation` execution is complete, so because in last line of the method you set value back to original - there are no updates in UI.

Asynchronous approach should work, because `await` operator will "pause" `InvalidOperation` method and return execution to the message loop which will update UI controls.

```
public async Task InvalidOperation()
{
    tempDisplay = Display;
    Display = "Invalid Operation";
        
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    Display = tempDisplay;
}
```

Comment: The async approach works--thank you. However, I don't quite understand the explanation. I tried splitting up the "Invalid Operation" method into two halves so that the display would be reset in a different method than where it was set and that didn't work. Also, "Display" Is a property that I've been using to set the display. It has to jump to that property to update it, and it has OnPropertyChanged() which suffices for any other events that update the display.

Comment: basically you can't do anything on the same thread that the app is using, while it's doing something.  I have something that may work for you though.  Try calling .invalidate() on the display control after updating it.

Comment: Value and control will be updated with "temporary" value, but actual UI will be updated only after `Negate` method is executed. Asynchronous approach "actually" breaks it in to pieces and updates UI in between